# Effectful update of Ref/MVar

Tags: scala, concurrency, functional-programming, scala-cats

I'd like to apply effectual computation to the value inside `MVar` or `Ref` and **atomically** update it in case the computation succeeds or put back the initial value (in case of `MVar`)/simply do nothing(in case of `Ref`) in case the operation fails.

**I. Ref-case**

```
val ref = Ref.of[IO, Int](0)

def foo(i: Int): IO[Int] = //... some effectual computation
```

Since atomicity matters and `Ref` does not provide `compareAndSet` operation unfortunately so it must be implemnted explicitly which does not look attracting.

**II. MVar-case**

MVar provides mutually-exclusion semantic, but the problem is that `bracket` does not allow us to `put` the computed value. Here is an example:

```
val mvar = MVar.of[IO, Int](0)

def foo(i: Int): IO[Int] = IO(i + 1)

for {
  mvar <- mvar
  i <- mvar.take.bracket(foo)(mvar.put) //puts back 0, not 1
} yield ()
```

Is there a way to implement such behavior at least for either `MVar` or `Ref`?

**UPD**:

I implemented it with `MVar`, but it looks rather ugly:

```
def updateAtomically(mvar: MVar[IO, Int], foo: Int => IO[Int]): IO[Int] = for {
  i <- mvar.take
  ii <- foo(i).onError{
    case t => mvar.put(i)
  }
  _ <- mvar.put(ii)
} yield ii
```

Comment: what's wrong with `for (i <- mvar.take; ii <- foo(i); _ <- mvar.put(ii)) yield ii`, without the `onError`?

Comment: @Martijn It will leave mvar empty causing deadlock.

Comment: "Ugly" is subjective. "Pretty" has little practical value. You can do e.g. `mvar.take >>= (i => foo(i).attempt.map(_.fold(_ => i, ii => ii)).flatTap(mvar.put))` but it wouldn't automatically make the code better.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Well, IMO ugly inhibits readability so prettifying it may have some value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`MonadError.redeemWith`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/MonadError.html#redeemWith%5BA,B%5D(fa:F%5BA%5D)(recover:E=%3EF%5BB%5D,bind:A=%3EF%5BB%5D):F%5BB%5D) for this:

```
def updateAtomically(mvar: MVar[IO, Int], foo: Int => IO[Int]): IO[Int] =
  for {
    i  <- mvar.take
    ii <- foo(0).redeemWith(_ => IO(i), ii => mvar.put(ii) *> IO(ii))
  } yield ii
```

And then:

```
import cats.Applicative.ops.toAllApplicativeOps
import cats.effect.{ ExitCode, IO, IOApp }
import cats.effect.concurrent.MVar

object Foo extends IOApp {

  def foo(i: Int): IO[Int] = IO(i + 1)
  def fooBar(i: Int): IO[Int] = IO.raiseError(new RuntimeException("BOOM"))

  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
    (for {
      mvar <- MVar.of[IO, Int](0)
      res  <- updateAtomically(mvar, foo)
      _    <- IO(println(res))
    } yield res).map(_ => ExitCode.Success)
}
```

Yields:

```
1
```

And:

```
def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
  (for {
     mvar <- MVar.of[IO, Int](0)
     res  <- updateAtomically(mvar, fooBar)
     _    <- IO(println(res))
   } yield res).map(_ => ExitCode.Success)
```

Yields:

```
0
```

Comment: Looks much nicer, thanks. I think it is neccasrry to implement recover as `mvar.put(i) *> IO(i)` to avoid empty MVar.

Comment: @SomeName Is the only place updating the `MVar` inside `updateAtomically`? If so, yes.